# Is it possible to implement asynchronous socket server but to receive messages on command

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I want to create server socket that will be able to always accept new clients, but it will have logic like "rounds". At the start of the round, only connected sockets will be able to participate, and server will expect answer from them (one answer at the time, then handling it and signalizing next socket that he must respond). While round is ongoing, other clients can connect, but they will have to wait for the next round.

My question is, can I do this with synchronous server or I have to use asynchronous (in this case, I don't know how to ask each client to respond at given time)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that rather than basing your sessions off the socket connections, when your clients connect they are assigned to a round and assigned a session token. If there a round is in progress they clients would be assigned to the next round and will not interact until they receive a message indicating that the next round has started. Doing this, you can manage the interaction from the server side and if a client looses connectivity they can reconnect and resubmit the session token they already have to continue with their session. You could have these session tokens timeout etc.

Comment: That is great advice.